# Can someone explain this line of code/command please?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting

Details would be appreciated!

I know that it supposed to be a shell script or something like that, but it would be greateful if someone more experienced in this field can tell me more about it.

```bsh
echo "" >> $HOME/.bashrc && echo "function cdls { cd "$1"; ls --color;}" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: https://explainshell.com/ might help to some extend.

Answer (score 3):

"**echo**" will (as the name states) echo a string of text to std out (usually the screen).

"**>>**" will append the output of the preceding command to a file path.

"**&&**" will run (based on the successful exit of the previous command) the successive command.

"**;**" will run (regardless of the successful exit of the previous command) the successive command.

"**function**" will create a function that will run in the Bash Shell.

"**$HOME**" is a reference (Bash Variable) to the user's OS home directory automatically created by Bash.

"**.bashrc**" is a hidden file (in the user's home directory) that is run when the user starts an interactive session.  It is often used for customizing the bash shell at the user-level.

"**cd**" is a directory change, change working directory.

"**ls**" lists files in the directory.  In this case "--color" is an argument that will emphasize certain directory elements with color, rather than using a single color.

"**$1**" is used to allow a user to pass an argument to this command as a variable.

So, in short, for...

```
echo "" >> $HOME/.bashrc &&
   echo "function cdls { cd "$1"; ls --color;}" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

The first line appends an "empty" line to **.bashrc** - simply for clarity's sake when someone looks at the file in the future.  The second line appends a new function called "**cdls**" which accepts an argument (a directory name), then changes the working directory to this location, and then immediately runs the "**ls**" command on this directory.

EDIT:  Please see comments from Celada and derobert on steve's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether $HOME/.bashrc is writable, by trying to append nothing to it:

```
echo "" >> $HOME/.bashrc &&
```

If the test is successful, the file is writable, append a function to it.  So that running `cdls foo` will display a coloured directory listing of directory "foo".

```
echo "function cdls { cd "$1"; ls --color;}" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: Will it though? Won't it `cd` into whatever `$1` was expanded to at the time the function was appended to `.bashrc`?

Comment: Indeed, the quoting is wrong too: should be `cd \"$1\"` — or better, the whole thing should be in single quotes, not double quotes, fixing both problems.

Comment: Also, rather than destructively adding newlines, `[[ -w $HOME/.bashrc ]]` would probably be a better test.